# Detection of alpha particle using semiconductor

Tags: semiconductor-physics, particle-detectors

I am trying to detect each instance of alpha particle (of about 5.6 Mev). What kind of semiconductor detector (like photo transistor, schottky diode etc) would be apt for this application?

TIA

Comment: Well, the proper one is a surface barrier detector from, e.g., https://www.ortec-online.com/products/radiation-detectors/silicon-charged-particle-radiation-detectors. Other devices you will have to reprocess to remove overlayers that may absorb the particles before getting to the depletion layer.

Comment: Thank you Jon for the information.